# python pandas : How to get the index of the values from a series that have matching values in other series?

Tags: python, pandas, series

I have these two series:

```
In [48]: serie1
Out[48]: 
0    A
1    B
2    C
3    A
4    D

In [49]: serie2
Out[49]: 
0    X
1    Y
2    A
3    Z
4    A
5    D
dtype: object
```

And for each value in serie1 I want to get the index/indexes from serie2.
Is this possible without iterating over values?
A possible solution would be to build a dataframe more or less like this:

```
       A      B      C      D
X    False  False  False  False                 
Y    False  False  False  False
A    True   False  False  False
Z    False  False  False  False
A    True   False  False  False
D    False  False  False  True
```

... and then get the index of the "True" values for each column

Comment: What's your desired output data structure?

Comment: I have no desired output data structure. I just need to be able to find the match/matches (index) of `serie1` values in `serie2`. The long answer is: `serie2` belongs to a dataframe that has another column (lets call it `long_name`) and I want to add the correct `long_name` to `serie1`. Unfortunately `serie1` and `serie2` are not related by index neither have the same length.

Comment: When you say *"... and then get the index of the "True" values for each column"*, you either want the boolean matrix/table/crosstabulation, or the indices of matches... or both. How do you want your indices of matches? as multiple series? as one dict? etc.

Comment: Seems you need `groupby()` as in `serie2.groupby(serie1).indices...` - see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think `serie2.index[(array(serie2)=='A').flatten()]` may work. `'A'` is the value you want to find index for.

Or this, which may be less readable: `serie2.index[(serie2=='A')[0]]`

Comment: Thank you, but that would imply to iterate over the columns (which in my real case are close to a million :/). Isn't there any quicker solution to verify where the values from series1 are in series2?

Comment: Can I assume that the unique values in `serie1` is a subset of the unique values in `serie2` (I think this has to be true). If so, will there be very large number of unique values in `serie1` or there will be only a few of them?

Comment: Yes. Unique values of `serie1` are a subset of unique values of `serie2`. The problem is that some values of `serie1` might have more than one match in `serie2` (therefore will have more than one `long_name` - see my explanation to @DSM if you please) and I don't want to loose that information.

Answer (score 0):

1) For the **boolean table of matches**: if you want a crosstabulation (only shows unique values, no repetitions), and then convert it to boolean:

```
serie1 = pd.Series(['A','B','C','A','D'])
serie2 = pd.Series(['X','Y','A','Z','A','D'])

pd.crosstab(serie2,serie1) > 0 

col_0      A      B      C      D
row_0                            
A      False  False   True   True
X       True  False  False  False
Y      False   True  False  False
Z       True  False  False  False
```

(Note that the row-index is automatically sorted by value, so not the order in which the values appear in `serie1`. You may be able to override that by playing with `.reorder_levels(...)`)

2) As for the **indices of matches**, to get them as a dict of arrays...

```
serie2.groupby(serie1).indices

{'A': array([0, 3]), 'C': array([2]), 'B': array([1]), 'D': array([4])}

# ... or as a list of arrays...
serie2.groupby(serie1).indices.values()

[array([0, 3]), array([2]), array([1]), array([4])]

# Here are alternatives with list comprehensions which are probably less efficient than `Series.groupby()` 
>>> [ np.flatnonzero(serie2.apply(lambda i2: i2==i1)) for i1 in serie1 ]
[array([2, 4]), array([], dtype=int64), array([], dtype=int64), array([2, 4]), array([5])]

>>> [ np.flatnonzero(serie2.apply(lambda i2: i2==i1)).tolist() for i1 in serie1 ]
[[2, 4], [], [], [2, 4], [5]]
```