# Comparing and finding identical entries in two particular columns of different Excel files

Tags: python, linux, excel, shell

I've got two files where there's a particular column I need to compare. On file1 has it on the fourth column. On file2 the needed column is on the third column. I need to find identical entries in these two files and their specified columns.

**File 1**

```
1 name addons wanted_column amount host
```

**File 2**

```
1 name wanted_column
```

I'm fine with Linux shell scripting, Python or anything on Windows as long it's freeware/free software.

Ok, I was asked, what I've tried. I copied the whole columns from file1 and file2 to text files. Then I tried this command:

```
diff --changed-group-format='' --unchanged-group-format='%=' file1.txt file2.txt > output.txt
```

This did give me the output I wanted, but when I'm comparing the data taken randomly from the wanted_column between file1 and file2, I can't find the entry from output.txt. That means this command coulnd't find every identical entry, it only found some.

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) Please [post your code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) here.

Comment: "I'm fine with Linux shell scripting, Python or anything on Windows " - then you're fine with everything on earth.

Answer (score 0):

[python pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.excel.ExcelFile.parse.html) has a lot of the functionality you're looking for.

For example, if I had two files, `file_1.xlsx` and `file_2.xlsx`, assuming the sheet names, were `Sheet_1` in each file, then I could create two `pandas.DataFrame`s, like so:

```
import pandas

f = pandas.ExcelFile('file_1.xlsx')
df_1 = f.parse('Sheet_1', index_col = None)

f = pandas.ExcelFile('file_2.xlsx')
df_2 = f.parse('Sheet_1', index_col = None)
```

I now have two very flexible data structures to manipulate and do comparisons.

**NOTE:** `df_1` and `df_2` will have **all of the columns** from that sheet.

So if I knew the name of the columns a priori, and say they were `f1_col` and `f2_col`, I could then examine those columns specifically by creating

```
series_1 = df_1['f1_col']
series_2 = df_2['f2_col']
```

Now you can take the information [provided in this Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21665162/python-pandas-how-to-get-the-index-of-the-values-from-a-series-that-have-match) and find entries that match between the two series.